# Momentum transfer between massive chargeless elementary particles

Tags: momentum, interactions

I am a little confused:
As far as I know momentum transfer between bodies happens due to the electrostatic interaction. It is then clear that momentum transfer between particles has to happen due to some interaction. But then how is momentum transfered between massive chargeless elementary particles? I don't know whether such particles exist to begin with, but because they are elementary and have no charge they would not be able to interact and therefore they can't transfer momentum.
My guess is that such particles don't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The electromagnetic force is only one of four forces through which elementary particles can interact. The other three forces are the weak force, the string force and the gravitational force, though gravitational interactions are negligible for elementary particles and can be ignored.

So for example neutrinos can elastically scatter off electrons through the weak force. The tree level diagram for this is the exchange of a $W$ particle:

[image: Neutrino elastic scattering]

Comment: okay, but by chargeless I mean the "generalized charge", i.e. not only electrostatic charges, but also nuclear charge.

Comment: @eeqesri as far as we know there are no particles that do not interact by any one of the three forces (though if such particles did exist they would be undetectable anyway).

Comment: makes sense. I have another question though: How can photons cause radiation pressure when they are considered fundamental particles?

Comment: @eeqesri that should be posted as a new question, if it hasn't already been asked, but before you post it, what exactly are you asking? Are you asking why photons can exert a pressure on electrons when photons aren't charged?

Comment: Ok I understand, yes that is exactly my question.

Comment: @eeqesri a photon doesn't have an electric charge, but it does have an electric dipole and it interacts with charge particles through the dipole.

Comment: ok that makes sense. thank you for clearing my doubt.